# how to pass value from animatedview to mainactivity

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a class called `AnimatedView.java` extends from `ImageView`,in this i have `onTouchEvent` method in which i have a value of type int named as count.my requirement i want pass this value to MainActivity for every time when event performed.please help me,here my code is

mainactivity is:

```
    Context context;
    int score=0;
    EditText text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        int i=intent.getIntExtra("score",score);
        EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText.setText(i);
    }
```

in animatedview.java:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("bharat", "ontouch called");
    int touchType = event.getAction();

    switch (touchType) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            a = event.getX();
            b = event.getY();
            touching = true;
            if (dm_touched) {
                x = (int) a - bm_offsetx;
                y = (int) b - bm_offsety;
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //x and y give you your touch coordinates
            a = event.getX();
            b = event.getY();
            touching = true;
            Log.d("bharat", "action_down called");
            if ((a > x) && (a < bm_w + x) && (b > y) && (b < bm_h + y)) {
                bm_offsetx = (int) x - x;
                bm_offsety = (int) y - y;
                count++;
                Log.i("bharat", "" + count);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent();
                intent1.putExtra("score", count);
            }
            dm_touched = true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        default:
            dm_touched = false;
            touching = false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an interface called for instance TouchCountListener, like this:

TouchCountListener.java

```
public interface TouchCountListener {

    public void setTouchCount();
}
```

In the ativity:

```
    public class yourActivity extends Activity implements TouchCountListener { 

        int animatedViewTouchCount=0;
         //..

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View  animatedView =  findViewById(R.id.ID_OFYOURANIMATEDVIEW);
        animatedView.setTouchCountListener(this);


           ///....
         }

   }
```

in animatedview.java:

```
    TouchCountListener mTouchCountListener;
     int animatedViewTouchCount=0;

   public void setTouchCountListener(TouchCountListener t){

       mTouchCountListener=t;
    }

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

       mTouchCountListener.setTouchCount(++animatedViewTouchCount);

     //...

}
```